# Schwarzschild Radius vs Gravitational Pull? Error in Model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, black-holes, software

I am a middle-school student who for fun has designed an simulation of gravity that finds the gravitational pull & then the Schwarzschild radius of the object, I have tested the program (coded in Python 3.3 for ease of Programming) and I have correctly calculated the Earths gravitational pull on surface where the paramters were given as $r = 6371000$ and $m = 5.972 * 10^{24}$ therefore my program used the following equation to get to the answer: 
$F = \frac{Gm}{r^2}$

$F = 9.81806072145$ m/s which is incredibly accurate with very little error if any. Then I have also used the famous Schwarz-child Radius equation to calculate the radii for it which my program used the following: 
$r_{s}  = \frac{2Gm}{c^2} = 1.48512969 * 10^{-27}  * 5.972 * 10^{24} = 0.00886919451 $

Which again points to correct value, with incredible accuracy, therefore I could conclude that the program should be correct for any other values as mathematics if in 1 instance its correct it should be correct with all other values.

Nevertheless, so I tried and this time I gave different values of this $r = 10 ^ {20}$ and $m = 10 ^ {50}$ and using the equation of $F = \frac{Gm}{r^2}$, I got the gravitational pull as being $F = 0.667384$ m/s which I assumed as being correct, but I then proceeded on to get the Schwarzchild Radii of the object using the equation: $r_s = \frac{2Gm}{c^2} = 1.48512969 * 10^{-27} *  10 ^ {50} = 1.48494276481 * 10^{23} $  which I got as the Schwarzschild radius.

Now I have manually also tested these results and I see no mistake on programs behalf, nevertheless I can say since $r < r_s$ as $ 10^{20} < 1.48494276481 * 10^{23}$  we can say the $r$ lies inside the radius but surely this should mean that nothing bad is happening as nothing is faster than light here, yet inside the radius everything should be going faster than light and remain an black hole.

Unless my calculations were mucked up please excuse me AND inform me.

If not can someone tell me if there is better way to calculate the gravitational pull.

Comment: Newtonian gravity is a weak-field static limit approximation of General Relativity. That means it works well when the gravitational field is relatively small and everything is moving slowly compared to light. When you want to consider extreme objects like black holes, Newtonian gravity will simply fail to be accurate in their vicinity. You need to do full-fledged GR to get the correct predictions.

Answer (score 6):

First we need to clear up a number of fundamental problems.

1. **Always** use units. You give all these numbers, but no sense of whether they are meters or nanoseconds or newtons or furlongs.
2. You should read up on [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). There is no point in writing out all those digits, since past the first one or two they are all uncertain. In science, writing out that many digits is a way of implicitly stating you are sure of the *precision* of your value to that level.
3. The formula for force is $F = Gm_1m_2/r^2$. The *acceleration*, which is what I think you want since you never specify an $m_2$, is $a = Gm/r^2$.

Now onto the physics. You are worried that nothing seems to have gone wrong inside the Schwarzschild radius. That's good intuition -- you should be in the habit of doing these sorts of sanity checks. However, you never wrote down a velocity as far as I can tell, so you don't *know* that nothing is going faster than light. All you have are accelerations, and accelerations can't be said to be more or less than $c$.

More fundamentally, though, Newtonian formulas shouldn't be expected to work near black holes. You need the full machinery of [general relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) to do things right, and Newtonian physics only approximates general relativity well for non-extreme cases. Black holes are the definition of extreme.

Now general relativity is a great thing to eventually learn, but I wouldn't recommend trying to handle it in middle school. So I'll just quote a result. The radial acceleration a test mass will feel outside a black hole (or any spherically symmetric object) of mass $m$ [has magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration#Surface_dwellers_on_a_planet)
$$ a = \left(\frac{r}{r-2Gm/c^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{Gm}{r^2}. $$
Newtonian physics would omit the quantity in parentheses. You can check that if you are well outside the Schwarzschild radius ($r$ is very large compared to $2Gm/c^2$), this correction is very close to $1$. However, as $r \to 2Gm/c^2$, this factor actually approaches infinity. This coincides with your intuition that you would feel an infinite gravitational pull at the Schwarzschild radius.

Inside the black hole one must be even more careful, since the roles of time and space become somewhat confused there. To even understand what happens qualitatively, I'm afraid general relativity is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Using the above GR modification to Newton's acceleration, you are right acceleration reaches infinity at the event horizon. However, the acceleration then becomes complex within the horizon (an imaginary number actually). You are right, things do become confused inside a black hole. So, if you want to have fun doing calculations of things happening inside the event horizon you will need to use complex arithmetic (real plus imaginary numbers).
I have had similar fun using complex angles of incidence in optical refraction problems to obtain angles of total internal reflection.